# What moves grant super armor?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Out of all of the moves in Super Smash Bros 4, a found that a couple give the player super armor for the duration (or atleast some of it). These include Rock Smash (Charizard), Little Mac's Side Smash Attack, and a couple others. But, what are **all** of the moves that give super armor?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/launch_resistance#In_Super_Smash_Bros._4)

Pit possesses some degree of armor while using the Upperdash Arm, while Little Mac gains armor for many of his grounded attacks, such as a sweeping uppercut and a rushing straight. Ganondorf now gets knockback resistance while charging his Warlock Punch. Bowser has been briefly seen in videos unflinching from attacks and has some sort of armor, as stated in this Miiverse post. This armor only applies at damage percentages below 75%, and even then, the higher the power of the attack, the more likely Bowser will flinch. This is mentioned in the "Bowser: Standing Tough" tip. Bowser Jr. has very little super armor on his side special move, Clown Kart Dash.

Pac-Man gains armor towards the end of his Power Pellet attack.

"Grab armor" no longer occurs for most special grabs and all regular grabs; grabs can be interrupted by lingering hitboxes.

Donkey Kong's customization move Stubborn Headbutt is shown with significant armor.

When a character does a forward smash with the Home-Run Bat, it will give the character super armor when it is about to be swung.

An Ore Club can also grant the character super armor while charging and releasing a smash attack.

Comment: Ike also has super armor on his fully-charged Eruption, as does Kirby when using a fully-charged Hammer Flip, or while charging the Giant Hammer custom.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed with Ike, his custom special move *Unyielding Blade* "grants super armor during the charge and lunge", at the cost of sideward speed and distance.